# PayPal Pay Operation - error 81002

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm not sure why this PayPal Pay operation is giving me this error even though I seem to have covered all the required fields:

> Error Code: 81002 Severity: Error Message: Unspecified Method (Method Specified is not Supported)"

```
string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
```

value of postData:

```
"actionType=PAY
&currencyCode=USD
&cancelUrl=https%3a%2f%2fexample.com%2fcancel
&returnUrl=https%3a%2f%2fexample.com%2freturn
&requestenvelope.errorLanguage=en_US
&receiverList.receiver(0).email=recipientemail%40gmail.com
&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=0.05
&VERSION=94.0
&USER=bizemail-facilitator_api1.gmail.com
&PWD=xxxxx
&SIGNATURE=xxxxxxxxx"
```

Here's how I do the post:

```
 SendRequest("https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp", postData);

 public string SendRequest(string url, string postData) 
 {
        var uri = new Uri(url);
        var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var requestData = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Timeout = (300*1000); //TODO: Move timeout to config
        request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
            stream.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
        }

        var response = request.GetResponse();

        string result;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII)) {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: accept an answer if it helped you, or the bounty is going to be wasted (you'll still loose it)

Comment: I havent had the chance to verify either answer. I guess I'll give you the bounty and award John extra bounty if you're wrong.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate it - and although I can't comment on John's answer as I only ever used the old PayPal Payments Standard, not the new API, even if he was right in your specific case, I am still technically correct (the best kind of correct) overall... so, far from wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `PAY` doesn't exist on the NVP api. Full list of methods supported by that API is found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/).

The `PAY` method, however, is defined in the `Adaptive Payments` API. Depending on your needs, you have two options:

- Change the endpoint to `https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PAY` and modify your values
- Use another method, like `DoDirectPayment`, but I'm not sure it does what you want to.

Comment: You're right the endpoint was not valid. I used the Mass Payment api with success: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/MassPay_API_Operation_NVP/ . Will award bounty soon

Answer (score 1):

I assume the value of postData is **before** you serialize it to a JSON string, instead of after as you say, since it is clearly **not** a JSON string.

If so, then it is already `x-www-form-urlencoded`, and you do not need to serialize it to a JSON string at all.

Or if you do after all, then change just this: `request.ContentType = "application/json";`

Comment: yeah, this didn't help but that's my fault cos I actually dont use SerializeObject I made the mistake of putting it in the question only. The real issue was api endpoint like JohnKiller said.